# JS replace with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to replace spaces after specific chars in the string:

Original string:

```
< TB :Sample Product Name >.< AT :some_property_name >
```

Expected output:

```
<TB:Sample Product Name>.<AT:some_property_name>
```

So:

spaces removed after "<"  and ">"

spaces removed between "TB and :" and "AT and :"

Partially working function (belive there is much better approach):

```
 private sanitizeText(text: string): string {
    return text.replace(/([<])\s+/g, (el1, el2) => {
      return el2;
    })
      .replace(/\s+([>])/g, (el1, el2) => {
        return el2;
      });
  }
```

Comment: Why don't you fix the source for the faulty output?

Comment: I cannot fix the source string

Comment: how about `text.replace(/(<)\s+|\s+(>)|(TB|AT)\s+(:)/g, '$1$2$3$4')`

Comment: @Sundeep seems to be fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
text.replace(/(<)\s+|\s+(>)|(TB|AT)\s+(:)/g, '$1$2$3$4')
```

If a capture group doesn't match, the corresponding backreference in the replacement section will give empty string. So, all the different cases can be combined with `|` here.